# Plastic enclosure, ESD considerations

Tags: esd, materials

I am working on a product with three plastic components: an injection molded enclosure (Lexan, polycarbonate), a 3D printed mounting tray (ESD PETG, carbon nanotubes) onto which my PCB is mounted, and 3D printed feet to keep the mounting tray fixed within the enclosure.

If sufficiently much charge builds up in the enclosure, my worry is that it might arc onto the PCB either spontaneously or when the mounting tray is mounted/dismounted, which will happen on a regular basis.

If the feet, which are in direct contact with both the enclosure and the mounting tray, were made from a slightly conductive ESD material, my understanding is that the electric potential would continuously equalize within the whole enclosure, preventing more violent static discharge events?

In an ideal world I would print everything using ESD filaments, but they tend to be more expensive, especially ESD TPU and similar flexible filaments which I would need for the feet. I am wondering if this would increase the ESD protection significantly or if the effect is marginal?